# Android widget not rendering, wrong xml in resource?

Tags: android, xml, resources, widget, manifest

I have some problem with displaying widget on the emulator.
I've created `widget_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/email_button"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map_button"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/info_button"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Then I've created new resource file `widget.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minHeight="250dp"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

And of course, I've added to manifest (after `</activity>` and before `</application>`):

```
<receiver android:name=".AppWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="//HERE MY widget.xml is not seen"/>
        </receiver>
```

And first of all, I don't know why, my `xml/widget` is not recognized by `Android Studio` as it's shown below:

[image: Not seen xml/widget]

And here's the structure of my project:

[image: Structure of the project]

I believe it's the reason, why the widget is not shown after I run the emulator. What's wrong with my code?

**EDIT**
Here, the problem was with launcher. After restarting, it works good. Yet, still the folder isn't seen in manifest. I don't know whether it's a bug or not, but if I write it manually, then everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the problem was with launcher. After restarting, it works good. Yet, still the folder isn't seen in manifest. I don't know whether it's a bug or not, but if I write it manually, then everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Added this to manifest?**

```
<activity android:name=".ExampleAppWidgetConfigure">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Actually, there's no need for me to do that.

Comment: from the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

Comment: This article just proves it's not neccessary for me. Not related to the problem which I solved in different way.

Comment: well, if you solved, then post it ...and accept the answer..it will help others!!